# Rules precedence in XKB

Tags: keyboard-layout

I customised the keyboard layout of my laptop to make use of two "dummy" keys. The standard keyboard driver does not manage these unusual keys. I first enabled them with `setkeycodes` commands in a *systemd* service.

Next I wrote a partial *symbols* keymap to describe which characters I desired under these two keys with plain (no), shift, altgr and shift+altgr modifier combination.

Records where added to *evdev.lst* to make my variant selectable by the desktop keyboard configuration tools.

Rules (or rather one or two lines) in *evdev* were added to describe my layout.

Up to this point, everything works fine: keyboard variant can be selected or deselected, unchanged keys send the standard character. New customised keys send the expected character provided a modifier key is also pressed. But, "plain" key does not send any character.

I dumped the keyboard configuration with `setxkbmap -print` to see that the *symbols* had an incorrect specification:

`xkb_symbols { include "pc+fr(mycustomkeyboard)+inet(evdev)+..." };`
(*not relevant information skipped and replaced by ellipsis)*

The above specification means definitions from `inet(evdev)` will override my definitions. One of my keys receives *XF86MenuKB*, the other *XF86Calculator* in their plain slots.

The correct specification would be:

`xkb_symbols { include "pc+inet(evdev)+fr(mycustomkeyboard)+..." };`

**Question:**

Is there a way to give precedence among partial rules in file *evdev* to achieve correct include order?

*If not:*

Are the pattern matching rules applied in the order in which they are listed in the file?

Can we have several sections with the same pattern? Said otherwise, does a later section override the previous one or is it merged into the previous one as an addition?

**Possibly related question:**

The following (unanswered as of my own post) question seems to complain about the same issue: 
[Override inet using xkb under Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29779072/override-inet-using-xkb-under-linux)